# Proof of a if statement total correctness

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, correctness, hoare-logic

The program I need to prove is

```
if(x>y){
   z=x;
}else{
   z=y;
}
```

And I need to show that [image: The picture of the formula] (where the P here should be the program above) is vaild, what I can do is to prove its partial correctness, but how to prove its total correctness?

Here is my proof of the partial correctness:

```
    {T}
    {(x>y -> x=max(x,y) ) ∧ (\neg(x>y) -> y=max(x,y) ) }  
    if (x>y)
        {T∧x>y}   If-statement
        {x=max(x,y)}   Implied
   z=x
        {z=max(x,y)}  Assignment
   else
        {T∧¬(x>y)}  If-statement
        {y=max(x,y)}  Implied
    z=y
        {z=max(x,y)}  Assignment
    fi  
        {z=max(x,y)}  If-statement
```

Comment: Can u kindly explain what partial correctness and total correctness is?

Comment: Show us the 'partial correctness'-proof. This may help.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire Partial correctness is to show that an algorithm yields the correct result (if any), total correctness is to also show that it always terminates.

Comment: Ok,I edit my question and add the partial correctness proof to it. @MrSmith42

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire   What Emily try to explain is  what I want to say

Comment: The program always does one comparison, one conditional jump forwards and one assignment; how could it not terminate?